# How to build a contingency table from multiple categorical attributes in R?

Tags: r, categorical-data

I'm trying to build a code or find away in R to transform my categorical data, obtained from a questionnaire, to a contingency table. Here is my sample data

```
Age = sample(c("15--25", "26-35", "36-45", " "45"), 90, replace = TRUE)
Volunteering_yr = sample(c(‘1yr’, ‘2yr’, ‘3yr>’), 90, replace = TRUE)
Q1 = sample(c(‘A’,’B’,’C’,’D, ‘E’), 90, replace =TRUE)
Q2= sample(c(‘A’,’B’,’C’,’D, ‘E’), 90, replace =TRUE)
Q3 = sample(c(‘A’,’B’,’C’,’D, ‘E’), 90, replace =TRUE)
Q4 = sample(c(‘A’,’B’,’C’,’D, ‘E’), 90, replace =TRUE)
Q5 = sample(c(‘A’,’B’,’C’,’D, ‘E’), 90, replace =TRUE)
Db = data.frame(Age,Volunteering_yr , Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5)
```

I would like to have the data reorganised by either volunteering yrs or Age but grouped by the count of answers (e.g. A, B, C, D, and E), something like this

[image]

Any suggestions?
Many thanks

Comment: Where are the Q columns? What do the numbers in the table represent, specifically?

Comment: The Q columns represent the questions, but I don't need them in my final table. thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `xtabs` function:

```
xtabs(~Volunteering_yr + Q1,Db)
               Q1
Volunteering_yr  A  B  C  D  E
           1yr   6  7  3  6  7
           2yr   6  4  1  5  7
           3yr>  7  6  5  8 12
```

I'm not aware of a simple base R function to do all quarters at once, but it would be easy enough with tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
Db %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(Age,Volunteering_yr)) %>% 
  group_by(Volunteering_yr, value) %>%
  tally() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = n)
## A tibble: 3 x 6
## Groups:   Volunteering_yr [3]
#  Volunteering_yr     A     B     C     D     E
#  <chr>           <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1 1yr                33    33    25    26    28
#2 2yr                28    18    20    23    26
#3 3yr>               43    46    33    31    37
```

Comment: Hi Ian, but this is only for Q1 and I want to have the sum of all A within the different years.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I used the pacman package to load libraries, but you could do them separately.

```
Db <- data.frame(Age=sample(c("15-25","26-35","36-45"), 90, replace=T),
Volunteering_yr=sample(c("1yr","2yr","3yr"), 90, replace=T),
Q1 = sample(c("A","B","C","D","E"), 90, replace =TRUE),
Q2 = sample(c("A","B","C","D","E"), 90, replace =TRUE),
Q3 = sample(c("A","B","C","D","E"), 90, replace =TRUE),
Q4 = sample(c("A","B","C","D","E"), 90, replace =TRUE),
Q5 = sample(c("A","B","C","D","E"), 90, replace =TRUE))

pacman::p_load(dplyr, magrittr)
Db %<>% mutate(across(c("Age", "Volunteering_yr"), factor))

with(Db, table(Age, Volunteering_yr))
```

```
      Volunteering_yr
Age     1yr 2yr 3yr
  15-25   9  16   6
  26-35   9  13   8
  36-45  11   7  11
```